# SSL issue in Python Django Elasticsearch environment

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, ssl

I am running a local dockerised Elasticsearch instance for a Python Django project, which I set up by following the [elastic docker guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html).

One of the steps involved downloading a CA cert file.
When the container is running I can connect to it using this cert file, or by ignoring certs altogether

```bash
# both of these work
curl --cacert my_cert.crt "https://${ELASTIC_USERNAME}:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}@localhost:9200"
curl -k "https://${ELASTIC_USERNAME}:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}@localhost:9200"
```

I have then added the `ELASTICSEARCH_DSN` details to my `settings.py` file as described in the [elasticsearch dsl docs](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) but there is no mention of certificates in the documents, and running commands gives an SSL error:

```bash
python manage.py search_index --rebuild

<snip>
elasticsearch.exceptions.SSLError: ConnectionError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002)) caused by: SSLError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002))
```

I'm not sure of the best way to resolve this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and it was very simple

```py
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    "default": {
        "hosts": [
            f"https://{elastic_username}:{elastic_password}@{elastic_hostname}:{elastic_port}"
        ],
        "use_ssl": True,
        "ca_certs": "relative/path/to/http_ca.crt"
    }
}
```

[relevant docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/8.0/config.html#_verifying_server_certificates)